# Hide a link for a duration once someone clicks it?

Tags: php, time, hyperlink, hide, duration

I'm building an app where people can click on song from a list of songs, and the song will be sent to my phone as a request. The problem I'm having is multiple people requesting the same song in a short span of time. What I'd like to do is hide a song if it has been requested in the last 2 hours or so. Meaning, once someone clicks a link, I would like that link to be hidden on the webpage for 2 hours after it has been clicked.

I'm assuming I'll need to use PHP for this, as the state of the link will need to be persistent no matter who accesses the site?

I'm trying to be as descriptive as possible, but I'm happy to provide an additional info you might need to help me get on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need somewhere to store the last time a song was requested, so that you can check (on page load) if that was more than 2 hours ago. Anything specific code-wise we can help you with?

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOverflow. Here's a quick note that you should read on asking questions. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you can create a .tmp file with the name of the song and time() inside it and check if the timer is inside the +120 range

Comment: @rickdenhaan - That sounds like what I'd need to accomplish this, but I guess I'm needing a little directions on roughly how this framework would work. I'm thinking it would be something like this; when a user clicks a song, a javascript onClick will write to a table in my mySQL database, logging the name of the song, and the timestamp it was requested. Then on the song list page, I would need something like a PHP IF statement for each link, checking that table to see if that song name is in the database, and if the timestamp is greater than 2 hours, then set the CSS to display: block?

Comment: @LeoTahk - This could possibly work. Would a use javascript to create the .tmp file, or PHP? I guess I just need a little direction on what languages would be best for this. I'm pretty good with Javascript, PHP, and mySQL.

Comment: if you want to hide the file from everyone, then the file should be on the server, so with php. its just `file_put_contents($song_name.'.tmp', (time() + 120));` atfter the user choses a song; and before you link the available songs you check them with `if(file_get_contents($song_name.'.tmp') >= time())...`